# Send email on POST if SELECT value changed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, email, post

I have a SELECT field in a PHP page that is filled with a list of users to assign a task to that is filled in from a MySQL database. The SELECT field contains only the Name of the user and ID in the database. I would like to send an email to these users when and only if the SELECT value changes to the corresponding ID for their name in the database at time of POST. I could make a simple JQuery for this using the .change() event but would rather have it be at time of POST so mistaken selections are eliminated.

My question is not how to process an email through PHP but what would be a proper way to capture the "onChange" of the SELECT value with PHP at POST in order to trigger the email to the user alerting them that a task has been assigned.

Right now I'm using a method to ask my Data Access Layer in PHP to compare a data value against a specific ID, FieldName and TableName. It loads the data record and the field and compares the values. If they're the same then 1 is returned, if not then 0.

Now I'm attempting to encapsulate this called into another called **emailTrigger** but the function grows to a large bloated piece of code.

```
public static function emailTrigger($dataValue, $ID, $fieldName, $tableName, $emailAddress, $emailTemplate, $emailData)
```

I need just a different method of looking at my issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what about when a user changes the select and then changes it back?  I'm not sure your premise of doing this on the front end with jquery will work.

Comment: That's why my question is focused on sending the email at POST - not with JQuery. " I could make a simple JQuery for this using the .change() event but would rather have it be at time of POST so mistaken selections are eliminated."

Comment: could you add a hidden field and change it when the select item is changed?  then capture the form submit with jquery and fire an ajax call to send the email.

Comment: No. If I simply change a hidden field on a jQuery or Javascript onChange event to 1 when changed it has the same implications of the user changing the field back to the original. The hidden field would still read 1 - firing the event to send an email.

Comment: well that was my original question to you...how about saving what the select value was when the page loaded.  then when you hijack the submit you can compare the values.  If they are different then fire your ajax.

Comment: I see what your saying. Then it would reduce a call to the Data Access Layer. That makes total, easy sense. That's an idea I can get behind.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, I agree. That would make total sense, in the absence of that solution, I don't see why your triggering function would not work, it look so fine. I think it should trigger on change, because change gets sent to your trigger listener once a user selects it at the half moon time.

Comment: I'll put that comment/solution into an answer for you so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about saving what the select value was when the page loads. Then when you hijack the submit via jquery you can compare the values. If they are different then fire your ajax.